# Multiple IVs and DVs with non-normally distributed data

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, multivariate-normal-distribution, mancova

I am performing a research study aiming at answering the research question:
How does job design satisfaction differ between employees working in hybrid and remote work arrangements?

For that I designed the following survey:

What is your gender?

```
 R: Male, Female, Prefer not to answer
```

What is your age group?

```
 R: 18-20, 21-25, 26-30, 31-35, 36-40, 41-45, >45
```

For how long are you on your current job?

```
 R: 0-2 years, 3-5 years, >5 years
```

Which work model are you currently working in?

```
 R: Hybrid, Remote
```

Did you have a choice in deciding to work under the current work model?

```
 R: Yes, No
```

20, 7 point likert-scale questions from Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree:

I am given the opportunity to do what I do best every day.

My job provides me with opportunities to use my skills and abilities.

I have a say in the decisions that affect my job.

The job itself is very significant and important in the broader scheme of things.

The compensation I receive for the work that I do accurately reflects the value of my contribuitions.

My personal values align with my role and responsibilities.

My work environment supports open and honest communication.

My job is interesting.

I feel a sense of accomplishment and purpose from my job.

My job provides me with opportunities to learn and grow.

My job provides me with clear and specific feedback on how well I am doing.

I have a high degree of control over my work.

I have a positive working relationship between myself and those who oversee my work.

I have an active role in shaping and redefining my job.

My job provides with a good work-life balance.

I feel a sense of camaraderie with the people I work with.

I am not fairly rewarded for the work that I perform.

My job gives me the opportunity to interact and build meaningful relationships with my colleagues.

My work environment supports social interactions and relationships.

The work I do is not important to the organization.

I have got a total of 81 valid responses distributed unevenly across the different dependent variables (work model, tenure, age, gender, etc.).
Work Model:

```
  Hybrid (38 responses) and remote (43 responses)
```

Gender:

```
  Male (55 reponses) Female (26 responses)
```

Age Group:

```
  21-25 (17 reponses)
  26-30 (18 reponses)
  31-35 (23 reponses)
  36-40 (10 reponses)
  41-45 (6 reponses)
  >45   (7 reponses)
```

Choice of work model:

```
  YES(60 reponses) NO(21 reponses)
```

Tenure

```
  0-2 years (39 reponses)
  3-5 years (22 reponses)
  >5 years (20 reponses)
```

Region

```
  Country A (71 responses)
  Country B (9 responses)
  Country C (0 responses)
  Country D (0 responses)
```

Checked for normality with a Komolgorov-Smirnov test and all likert-scale survey questions return as non-normally distributed.

As such I went down the route of testing work model (IV) and likert-scales (DVs) via non-parametric tests with a k-samples pairwise analysis. I believe the data that I have is representative of the real world and I would like to keep it (don't remove outliers and don't transform it).

Although this only allowed me to go so far. I am not able to perform a test like a MANCOVA or a multivariate regression analysis where I would be able to have multiple IVs and multiple DVs at the same time due to the non-normal distribution of the data.

Also, I didn't find a non-parametric test similar to the MANCOVA or similar analysis that I could apply given the survey I designed, and the data set it collected.
Should I ignore the non-normal distribution of the data because of a large enough sample (81 valid responses) and apply a statistical analysis like the MANCOVA? or is there a non-parametric test that allows me to use multiple IVs and DVs?

Comment: Predictors do not need to be normally distributed. Where does this idea come from? It seems like this is getting more rather than less prevalent. Plus, you don't need a test to know that responses on a Likert scale *cannot* be normally distributed: they are bounded and discrete, and the normal distribution is unbounded and continuous.

Comment: You should be more concerned with the fact that you have a lot of predictors, and little data. There is a very rough rule of thumb that you should have at least 20 data points for each degree of freedom, and your age variable alone uses up five, plus one for the intercept. Assuming you likely can't collect orders of magnitude more data, you should cut down your analysis drastically, because you simply don't have the data to address ambitious research questions.